# Need advice executing awk commands in ansible

Tags: awk, ansible

I have some SQL script files which have the same naming convention.

```
pole15432-pole15435.sql 
pole15435-pole15447.sql 
pole15447-pole15453.sql 
pole15453-pole15454.sql
```

I want to filter out only the files which are greater than: `pole15435-pole15447.sql`. I can do this directly on the terminal via:

```bash
ls -1 pole* | awk '$1 > "pole15435-pole15447.sql"'
```

which results :

```
pole15447-pole15453.sql
pole15453-pole15454.sql
```

however, executing the same from ansible gives me no results.

```
    - name: Find upgrade scripts that need to be executed
      shell: ls -1 pole* | awk '$1 > "pole15392-pole15402.sql\"'
      #shell: "ls -1 | sed -n /pole15392-pole15402.sql/,//p"
      args:
       chdir: /data/releases/Upgrade Scripts
      delegate_to: localhost 
      register: scripts
    
    - debug:
       msg: "{{scripts}}"
result:
changed: [10.101.96.176] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "ls -1 pole* | awk '$1 > \"pole15392-pole15402.sql\"'", "delta": "0:00:00.010166", "end": "2022-10-15 18:01:04.441383", "rc": 0, "start": "2022-10-15 18:01:04.431217", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

can someone help please?

Comment: Please don't multi-post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74081432/1745001

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Filter out only the files which are greater than: pole15435-pole15447.sql"***

A: Given the file

```yaml
  file: pole15435-pole15447.sql
```

and the list of files

```yaml
  files:
    - pole15453-pole15454.sql
    - pole15432-pole15435.sql 
    - pole15435-pole15447.sql 
    - pole15447-pole15453.sql
```

Sort the list, get the index of the file, and create the slice

```yaml
files_sort: "{{ files|sort }}"
file_index: "{{ files_sort.index(file) }}"
files_select: "{{ files_sort[file_index|int + 1:] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  files_select:
  - pole15447-pole15453.sql
  - pole15453-pole15454.sql
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    files:
      - pole15432-pole15435.sql 
      - pole15435-pole15447.sql 
      - pole15447-pole15453.sql 
      - pole15453-pole15454.sql

    files_sort: "{{ files|sort }}"
    file: pole15435-pole15447.sql
    file_index: "{{ files_sort.index(file) }}"
    files_select: "{{ files_sort[file_index|int + 1:] }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: files_sort
    - debug:
        var: file_index
    - debug:
        var: files_select
```

---

If you want to user *awk* put the name of the file into a variable. For example, given the tree

```bash
shell> tree sql/
sql/
├── pole15432-pole15435.sql
├── pole15435-pole15447.sql
├── pole15447-pole15453.sql
└── pole15453-pole15454.sql
```

the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    file: pole15435-pole15447.sql

  tasks:

    - shell:
        cmd: ls -1 pole* | awk '$1 > "{{ file }}"'
        chdir: "{{ playbook_dir }}/sql"
      register: scripts
    
    - debug:
       var: scripts.stdout_lines
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  scripts.stdout_lines:
  - pole15447-pole15453.sql
  - pole15453-pole15454.sql
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I actually wanted a simpler approach and hence was looking for awk but for some reason, the command yields no results via Ansible. I have tried declaring the variable and then calling it in the shell. the results are blank : "changed": true, "cmd": "ls -1 pole* | awk '$1 > \"pole15392-pole15402.sql\"'", "delta": "0:00:00.009375", "end": "2022-10-16 16:17:42.643614", "rc": 0, "start": "2022-10-16 16:17:42.634239", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with ls -1 pole* | awk '$1 > "{{ file }}"'. the -1 parameter pulls more than the file name and awk is not able to process that via Ansible. Using -1 (one) fixed it